# Add node at the end(Struct Node in C)

Tags: c, nodes

```
list *add_item(list *l, int value){
list *temp;
temp = malloc(sizeof(list));
temp->data = value;
temp->next = l;
l = temp;
return l;}
```

This is the code to insert on the front of the list. How can i change this?? I want to insert at the end.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it could be:

```
list *add_item(list *l, int value){
list *temp;
temp = malloc(sizeof(list));
temp->data = value;
temp->next = 0;
l->next = temp;
return l;}
```

if *l is head of list

```
list *add_item(list *l, int value){
list *temp;
temp = malloc(sizeof(list));
temp->data = value;
temp->next = 0;
list* tmp = l;
while(tmp->next) tmp = tmp->next;
tmp->next = temp;
return l;}
```

Comment: *l was the head of list. I made even a list called head
list* head = NULL;
list *create_list(int value){
 head = malloc(sizeof(list));
 head->data = value;
 head->next = NULL;
 return head;
}

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through the list until `temp->next == NULL` and then add the node there. You can keep a `last` reference to the last element if you don't want to iterate. Also, the line `l = temp` does nothing.

Comment: because of `return l;` the line `l = temp;` does something. So it returns the first node instead of the second node.

Comment: You could just write `return temp;`

Answer (score 0):

Traverse through the list, I assume you have `list->next` pointing to `null` at the end of List. Find that position and give reference to the newly created element.

*assuming you have a head pointing to the first element of the list*

```
List *temp = head;
List *newElement = malloc(sizeof(List));
List *currNode;
//some assignment 
while(temp!= null )
{
     currNode = temp;
     temp = temp->next;
}
currNode->next = newElement;
```

Comment: your code will cause a segfault. notice that after it comes out of the while loop, `temp==null` holds.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
list *add_item(list *l, int value) {
    list *head, *temp;
    head = l;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(list));
    temp->data = value;
    temp->next = NULL;
    while(l->next != NULL) {
        l = l->next;
    }
    l->next = temp;
    return head;
}
```